# unity 2D 5.0: collision with colliders, one with "is trigger" checked and one with "is trigger" unchecked

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I am a beginner in Unity 5.0.

It is hard to describe my problem, so I included 3 images. please see following:

http://frankiegamescom.ipage.com/question.html

please help. Thanks.

Comment: Links break, could you copy the bulk of your explanation as text in to the question (seems like you've explained the problem pretty well with those words - how do you have the car act as a trigger to one collision and as a rigid body to another.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should be changing the isTrigger property of your car_player in your code. It looks like this would be a better solution:

Leave the box colliders on your car and road blocks to not be triggers.  Let the grass's box collider be a trigger. 2D Rigidbodies would only need to be on the the road blocks and the car. Then the car should stop when hitting the road block if you're moving it correctly; that is by [Rigidbody2D.AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) or [velocity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html).

If you are using Transform.Translate then then I think you would need to add a [Rect.Overlaps](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.Overlaps.html) infront of your car and check for collisions manually.

Edit: Looking at your screenshots again, it looks like just leaving your cars isTrigger to false and leaving the grass colliders isTrigger to true might solve your problem. And maybe use [OnTriggerStay2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerStay2D.html) to to pass a multiplier for your drag.